# Have li:nth-child effect only parent list and not child list

Tags: html, css

I am able to achieve the effect I want but wondering if there is a better way of coding. I am using `li:nth-child()` to select parts of a parent list I want to add a border to.

However I do not want these to effect sub lists inside the parent list.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
<li>Link 1

    <ul>
        <li>Sub Link 1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav li:nth-child(-n+3) {
    border-left: 4px solid #FFC50A;
}
```

How do I get the "Sub Link 1" to not have a border without using:

```
.nav > li > ul > li {
    border: 0px !important;   
}
```

Should I just give the parent list a class to make the list have a border instead of using `.nav li:nth-child(-n+3)`?

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpkb8obL/)

Comment: Why don't you use `.nav > li:nth-child(-n+3)`? So that it won't select the inner list items.

Comment: I currently use that code. See the fiddle. If you take out border: 0px !important; towards the bottom, you will see that the border effects the inner lists as well. Hover over link 1 - http://jsfiddle.net/1cnhgfvw/

Comment: @AndrewH I think he meant it like in `.nav > li:nth-child(-n+3) { border-left: 4px solid #FFC50A; }`

Comment: I don't see ' > ' in the relevant rules nor here in your description.

Comment: as Hasem said, you need to use `.nav > li:nth-child(-n+3)`. Have a look at this fiddle, I've removed the `border: 0px !important; ` part and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/BeNdErR/kpkb8obL/1/

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice in the comment. You're right, I have to pay more attention. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in comments, you could use **[child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)** in order to prevent for the inner list items from be treated by the selector, as follows:

```css
.nav > li:nth-child(-n+3) {
    border-left: 4px solid #FFC50A;
}
```

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/1cnhgfvw/2/)**

> **[5.6 Child selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors)**
>   A child selector matches when an element is the child of some element.
>   A child selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, due to the cascading nature of CSS, I don't think this is explicitly possible ([yet](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#all-shorthand)).

I think if I were implementing this, I might define parent and child classes for each list. This would help with specificity, but you can run into problems if the HTML is generated instead of hand-coded.

EDIT:

Another thing I just thought of is (depending on your scalibility needs here), you could try just styling children with your overrides like so:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpkb8obL/)

```
    <li>Link 1
        <ul>
            <li class="childList">Sub Link 1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

and

```
.childList {
position: relative;
width: 175px;
padding: 0;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 20px;
color: #555;
border: 0px !important;
```

}

. I'm not really sure how this list will be balanced, so to speak, so this could be a bad answer as well.